# statically compiling 32 bit program on a 64 bit linux machine

Tags: linux, compiler-errors, static-libraries

I install libevent library using `configure, make, make install`.
my computer is

```
[esolve@kitty esolve]$ uname -r
3.6.10-2.fc16.x86_64
```

I wrote a program which uses libevent.  Since I want to distribute this program to many remote hosts where libevent is not installed. So I want to compile the program statically, using

```
gcc -o myprogram mypro.c /usr/local/lib/libevent.a -lpcap -lrt
```

now I notice some of the remote machines are 32 bits, not 64 bits

so I want to use `-m32` to compile

```
gcc -m32 -o myprogram mypro.c /usr/local/lib/libevent.a -lpcap -lrt
```

but I got errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `/usr/local/lib/libevent.a(event.o)' is incompatible with i386 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `/usr/local/lib/libevent.a(log.o)' is incompatible with i386 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `/usr/local/lib/libevent.a(evutil.o)' is incompatible with i386 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `/usr/local/lib/libevent.a(select.o)' is incompatible with i386 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `/usr/local/lib/libevent.a(poll.o)' is incompatible with i386 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `/usr/local/lib/libevent.a(epoll.o)' is incompatible with i386 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `/usr/local/lib/libevent.a(signal.o)' is incompatible with i386 output
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

are there any workaround for this?
thanks!

Comment: Did you try installing 32-bit libraries?

Comment: no, I installed it using configure make make install. how to install 32-bit from `configure make make install`?

Comment: Which distro is this?  Some with extensively curated package repositories will have 32-bit libs available for easy install. (Ubuntu, for example has this)

Comment: my OS is fedora 16, the libevent is 1.4

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use your own compiled library in 32 bits mode (e.g. `libevent`) you should `configure` it with `CC='gcc -m32'` to have it compiled in 32 bits mode.

If you want to have both 32 & 64 bits versions of the same library you should build the library twice, with different `configure` options (don't forget to `make clean` between builds), perhaps changing the `--prefix` or `--libexec-prefix`

You could also consider having an entire 32 bits distribution in your `chroot`-ed environment (and then you'll need to `bind` mount some directories like `/proc`, `/dev`, etc...).

Comment: is it possible to enable both 32-bit and 64-bit library?

Comment: can you give more details on `configure` options and --prefix options? I mean the complete commands , I'm afraid I will do wrong things. thanks

Comment: No, you have to carefully read the documentation, and also run `configure --help`